# Bootstrap Modal Does Not Open inside routed page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using angularjs and single-page-application approach for my app via ui.router. Now I just want to show a modal  when a button (inside one of that route) is clicked.

I used a basic modal that works in a simple page but doesn't work in my case(probably because of the routing). I read that there are several ways for doing this, even by exploiting ui.router and nested state but I didn't get it, can anyone show me a simple working example for doing this?

This is my module app

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router",'ngTagsInput']);

// define route configurations inside app.config
// injecting dependencies
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider,
                     $urlRouterProvider) {


    $stateProvider
        .state('Home', {
            url: "/Home",
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "HomeCtrl"

        })
        .state('Profilo', {
            url: "/Profilo",
            templateUrl: "views/profilo.html",
            controller: "ProfileCtrl"
        })
        .state('Altro', {
            url: "/Altro",
            templateUrl: "views/altro.html",
            controller: "AltroCtrl"

        })
});
```

and this is my simple modal to open in view handled by profile controller

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">button</button>

<div class="modal fade" id=myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using a third-party library like [UI-Bootstrap Modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal), AngularJS directives without any dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript.